# Define window title when using TitleAreaDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, titleareadialog

I am working with an Eclipse RCP (e3) and I am using TitleAreaDialog. I succeeded to add the Title inside of it and the text as well as all the other components. However, what I was uncapable of doing is to add a title to my window. I tried everything that came to my mind and searched on the internet but with no luck. I wonder if it is even possible. Anyway, if you do have the solution, please let me know.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

To set the text of the window title use the `Shell.setText` method. The cleanest way to do this is to override the `configureShell` method:

```
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell newShell)
{
  super.configureShell(newShell);

  newShell.setText("Window title");
}
```

This applies to `TitleAreaDialog`, `TrayDialog` and `Dialog` (and others).